# Android ConstraintLayout failed to instantiated

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I am getting an error while working with ConstraintLayout. the error look like this,

```
Failed to instantiate one or more classes
```

`The following classes could not be instantiated`
`-android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout`

i have installed both Constraint Layout for android and Solver for constraint Layout.

[image: Screenshot of SDK Tools]

I have this dependency in my app gradle File:`build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'

compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'


//butterknife for view binding
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.6.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.6.0'
//bottom bar navigation
compile 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:2.3.1'
//fragment managment library
compile 'com.ncapdevi:frag-nav:2.0.1'
//for ripple animation
compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

My XML Layout is this -

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.cr.priyankjain.customrom.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

so my question is that how can i remove this error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just solved the issue this [FragNav](https://github.com/ncapdevi/FragNav) dependency library was causing all the issue with layout so i just removed this line from gradle file.

```
compile 'com.ncapdevi:frag-nav:2.0.1'
```